# How to handle "CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed" in iOS

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, cfnetwork

Some times i'm getting `CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed -(9806)` in my code,but i'm not sure why this is happening as my code runs smoothly,except when i run it in iOS 6 and then on iOS 7 64-bit i get this warning.
Can anybody suggest me, how to handle this issue ?

Comment: Please stop editing questions en masse. When you do this with old questions all you are doing is bumping them to the top of the timeline. This is bad as new questions are pushed down.

Comment: @Fogmeister Day before yesterday 31 of the top 100 active iOS questions were courtesy of Arun_k

Comment: @Fogmeister i had no idea about this thing,thanks for the info

Comment: I'm assuming from your tags, this is when using `NSURLConnection`. Can you specify that in the question please, and where in your code you're seeing this error?

Comment: Sorry @MikeAbdullah,this issue i was facing in my previous project and currently i'm not working for that company and i don't really remember that part of the code as there were 6-7 requests we are firing upon application launch.

Comment: This might help when trying to understand the error code: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libsecurity_ssl/libsecurity_ssl-32463/lib/SecureTransport.h

Comment: You may have missed to set [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Normally when I get `CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed -(*)` Its because of my local wifi network (device is connected to network but *not* the internet)

Try it again on another network (3G is the quickest solution for me)

Comment: But there any way to handle this,so that my app won't crash.

Comment: @JoshK can you put some of implement this part?

Comment: This does not make your app crash. These are just warnings. make sure you have strong reachability for all your requests. ZCheers

Answer (score 11):

This could also happen because of iOS 9. iOS 9 and OSX 10.11 require TLSv1.2 SSL for all hosts you plan to request data from unless you specify exception domains in your app's Info.plist file.

You can find more info here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/

Or Steven Peterson's answer here, which is quite clear:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30720929/1485701

Comment: Great advice. Just one more thing to add which is not described in Steven Peterson answer which is pointed. The default value of `NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy` is true, therefore your server should has it enabled also(which is recommended to fix some vulnerabilities) or you should explicity set it to false in your iOS app(not recommended).

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue and after I have confirmed that the server is getting the POST  the solution was this:

- Clean the project: Product -> Clean
- Delete your app from the iOS device/iOS Simulator and quit the Simulator
- Compile your app and run it

In my case, simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and in my case the solution was that in my code I wrote

```
initWithScheme:@"https"
```

instead of

```
initWithScheme:@"http"
```

So make sure you use the correct protocol

Comment: it wasn't the problem with me,as all the WS i was using was HTTPS only

Comment: But, what happen if you need consume data over https?