# SSL Handshake failed error (-9806) in ios devices only

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl, handshake

when connecting to  service i"m getting this error in iphone and ipad . But its works fine in android app and in chrome and firefox . The same link can be opened in mac safari browser after accepting the untrusted certificate, But not in iphone/ipad safari browser ?
Somebody have any solutions?

we are currently using a self signed certificate to make the webservice trusted .

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21318200/cfnetwork-sslhandshake-failed-9806-error-using-nsurlsession-when-app-in-backg and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244815/getting-cfnetwork-sslhandshake-failed-9806-error

Comment: Please add more details, especially the URL. Safari and iOS have a more strict validation of certificates then others, especially related to wildcards.

Comment: hi , thanks guys for your response. It was actually a certificate issue , i installed a root certificate provided by the server team in all our test devices , its working fine now