# Pod update to Google Maps SDK for iOS has an error

Tags: ios, google-maps, sdk, cocoapods

Has anyone come across this error message when updating the google maps ios sdk pod to version 1.12.3?

```
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/xp/fnfrqb9x08jd11zbfy26d4kr0000gn/T/d20160316-54997-6ypf9q/file.tgz https://www.gstatic.com/cpdc/6228ff6656915b62-GoogleMaps-1.12.3.tar.gz --create-dirs

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100        580k       0 580k   0       0        3112   0        --:--:--  0:03:10 --:--:--     0curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -9806
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an issue with the ssl certificate, see the comments section in this post:
[SSL Handshake failed error (-9806) in ios devices only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498088/ssl-handshake-failed-error-9806-in-ios-devices-only)

Comment: So how do I go about fixing it?