# CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806) - xcode

Tags: ios, cordova, ssl, ionic-framework

Has anyone ran into this issue?
My app was working fine and this error started to show up when I updated to the latest Xcode. These is the error:

```
CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
```

I have already checked and tried this solution [CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720813/cfnetwork-sslhandshake-failed-ios-9/30720929#30720929) but it did not work for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: He have you found any solution for this issue rather than changing the network from wifi to 3g/LTE

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution from [CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720813/cfnetwork-sslhandshake-failed-ios-9/30720929#30720929)  should work. Please check whether you are doing everything correctly. Please try to make a clean install of your app or (and) reset iOS Simulator + clean Xcode project

Also please check your Internet reachability as described here:
[How to handle "CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed" in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19922717/how-to-handle-cfnetwork-sslhandshake-failed-in-ios)

Comment: I have checked and tried to their solutions and it did not work. I have also cleaned the project, removed the app and installed it again without luck.

Comment: @OmarAlejandroChacinOrtega how are you trying to add the keys to your .plist file? please try right click on .plist file + "Open As" + "Source Code" + set NSAppTransportSecurity key block just before other <key>...</key> instance

Comment: I have done so. I added it like: 
    `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>`

It did not work either and I have internet.

Comment: please try to reset iOS simulator or clear web-cache on device

Comment: Still no luck... This seems to be very estrange. I will keep trying. Thanks !

Comment: The app still refuses to connect. I keep getting this error:

`CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
 NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)`

Comment: sometimes it could be just a network error, try to switch from WiFi to 3G/LTE or change the network in some other way